# Generate sequential Id for primary key column in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

How can I generate a Sequential guid for a primary key column in NHibernate. I know how to do that auto increment stuff. But I don't know how to create a sequential Guid for primary key.

In the database, data type of Id column is `uniqueidentifier`. I've checked the official docs and some other web search results. But I'm not able to find any solution. Here is what I have now:

```
public UserMap()
{
    Table("Users");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Username, x => x.NotNullable(true));
    Property(x => x.Email, x => x.NotNullable(true));
    Property(x => x.PasswordHash, x =>
    {
        x.NotNullable(true);
        x.Column("password_hash");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that like so:

In my business entity classes

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    ...
}
```

The fluent mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
```

Read [this](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/05/21/using-the-guid-comb-identifier-strategy.html) about Guid.comb

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc by Adam Bar

#### [Mapping-by-Code - Id, NaturalId](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html)

Let me cite:

> The most common primary key mapping is available through Id method.
>
> ```
> Id(x => x.Id, m =>
> {
>     m.Column("id");
>
>     m.Generator(Generators.Native, g => g.Params(new
>     {
>         // generator-specific options
>     }));
>
>     m.Length(10);
>     m.Type(new Int32Type());
>     m.Access(Accessor.Field);
> });
> ```
>
> There are several features missing - like unsaved-value (will be added
>   in NHibernate 3.3) or DDL column options.
>
> Probably the most important option is Generator. It specifies the way
>   NHibernate (or database) generates unique values. There are 8
>   predefined types of generators available through static Generators
>   class:
>
> ```
> public static class Generators
> {
>     ...
>
>     // Guid
>     public static IGeneratorDef Guid { get; }
>
>     // sequential Guid
>     public static IGeneratorDef GuidComb { get; }
> ```

So, based on that, we can adjust the mapping like that:

```
public UserMap()
{
    Table("Users");
    Id(x => x.Id, m =>
    {
        m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you could CREATE SEQUENCE and use it for IdGeneration. For example:

`mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("TableSequence");`

For this to work, you have to make sure, that in your `hibernate-configuration` you have property set as:
`<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>` or newer.

To Create a sequence, you could use Migration script as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @SequenceStartId INT;

/* Create TableSequence */
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sequences WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableSequence'))
BEGIN
   DROP SEQUENCE dbo.[TableSequence]
END

SET @SequenceStartId = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM dbo.[Table]) + 1;

SET @Command = FORMATMESSAGE('
      CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TableSequence
      START WITH %i  
      INCREMENT BY 1 AS INT;
   ', @SequenceStartId)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command
```

More about sequences:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15